# No totalcross, como mostrar um popup quando eu clicar em um botão dentro de um accordion?

Tags: java, totalcross

Tenho uma aplicação com Totalcross, estou utilizando o accordion e dentro de cada abba tenho um botão atualizar, como faço para quando clicar no botão atualizar seja exibido um popup com uma mensagem "Dados atualizados"?
Tentei utilizar "addPenListener" e "onEvent" mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Seria bom você mandar o seu código para entendermos onde você errou quando usou o onEvent. Já com o addPenListener, você deve ter confundido com addPressListener.

Segue o código da criação de um accordion com um Button dentro, que quando você clica dispara uma popup com uma mensagem.

```
public class AccordionTela extends Container {

AccordionContainer ac;
Label lb;

public AccordionTela(){
    setBackColor(Color.WHITE);
}

public void initUI(){
    ac = new AccordionContainer();
    ac.setFont(font.asBold());

    add(ac, CENTER, TOP+30, PARENTSIZE+85, PREFERRED);
    ac.setBackForeColors(0xadd8e6,Color.BLACK);
    ac.add(ac.new Caption("Legenda"), LEFT, TOP, FILL, PREFERRED);

    lb = new Label("Texto");
    ac.add(lb,LEFT,AFTER,FILL,PREFERRED);

    Button bt = new Button("botão");
    bt.setBackForeColors(Color.WHITE, Color.BLACK);
    ac.add(bt,LEFT,AFTER,PREFERRED+10,PREFERRED+10);

    bt.addPressListener(e -> {
        new MessageBox("Aviso","Dados atualizados").popup();
    });
}

}
```

Comment: Ótima explicação e código muito elegante e claro. Parece até que trabalhamos desenvolvendo juntos ;-)